# Is there a better way to structure the express entry point?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm relatively new programmer. What I'm currently trying to do is to create a good code base, from which I can then develop the API I need. The requirements for that are, that I want to use NodeJS with Express and TypeScript. So I've created a new express bootstrapped project with the express-generator and started to convert the code into a TypeScript conform structure.

My question starts here: 
I moved and renamed the "root/bin/www" file into "src/bin/index.ts". My tslint is set to "recommended" and therefore the "no-shadowed-variable" is true. So I got a "no-shadowed-variable" error in my index.ts, because the variable port is defined twice. Once in the outer function, as well as in the "onListening" function. So I started to separate the "onListening" and the "onError" function into a new module called "expressHandlers.ts", and the "normalizePort" function into "normalizePort.ts".

You can see the full project structure on: **https://github.com/owme/server-template/tree/master/src/bin**

It's currently working right now, but would you please let me know if you think this approach to rename and modularize the bin/www is reasonable?

Btw. I had to rewrite parts of the "onListening" function, because addr can be of type AddressInfo | string | null. And null is not a valid entry of the variable.

So my index.ts now exports the two variables { port, server } to be available for normalizePort. What is left, in the index.ts is the following:

---

index.ts:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 * @private
 */

import { createServer } from 'http';
import app, { set } from '../app';
import { onError, onListening } from './expressHandlers';
import { normalizePort } from './normalizePort';

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

const server = createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Module exports.
 * @public
 */

export {
  port,
  server
};
```

---

normalizePort.ts:

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val: number|string): number|string|boolean {
  const port: number = (typeof val === 'string') ? parseInt(val, 10) : val;

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Module exports.
 * @public
 */

export {
  normalizePort
};
```

---

expressHandler:

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 * @private
 */

import debug from 'debug';
debug('server:server');
import {
  port,
  server
} from './index';

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error: NodeJS.ErrnoException) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  const bind = (typeof port === 'string') ? `Pipe ${port}` : `Port ${port}`;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      debug(`${bind} requires elevated privileges`);
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      debug(`${bind} is already in use`);
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  const addr = server.address();
  let bind = null;
  if (addr !== null) {
    if (typeof addr === 'string') {
      bind = `pipe ${addr}`;
    } else {
      bind = `port ${addr.port}`;
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error('The Host-Address is null');
  }
  debug(`Listening on ${bind}`);
}

/**
 * Module exports.
 * @public
 */

export {
  onError,
  onListening
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Since your code is working now and you appear to be just asking about code style and organization, I wonder if this is more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @jfriend00, thank you for the info. I didn't know this community.

Comment: If you post there, they are very strict about following the rules for "on topic" posts and rules about how you post.  Please read and understand their rules before posting.